# Multiple comments.xml files from PhpWord

Tags: php, phpword

I am using PhpWord to create a document that contains comments. I can create the file successfully, but when I try to open it, Word reports that it contains unreadable content. Although Word will continue to open the file, and the comments appear to be in the correct places, I would still like to find an elegant solution that prevents Word from displaying the warning.

I renamed the .docx file to a .zip and found that the package contains 2 comments.xml files.

[image: Duplicate comments.xml files]

The two files are identical, except that one contains the id for the comments, and the other does not.

[image: XML file with Comment ID]

[image: XML file without Comment ID]

Below is the code. It works fine if I do not include the comments. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
ob_start(); // output buffering is turned on
require_once('bootstrap.php');

// Creating the new document...
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$phpWord->getCompatibility()->setOoxmlVersion(15);

// Adding an empty Section to the document...
$section1 = $phpWord->addSection();

      // A comment
      $comment = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Comment('Authors name');
      $comment->addText('Test comment', ['bold' => true]);
      $phpWord->addComment($comment);

      $textrun = $section1->addTextRun();
      $textrun->addText('This ');
      $text = $textrun->addText('is');
      $text->setCommentRangeStart($comment);
      $textrun->addText(' a test');
                        
ob_clean();

$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'PHPWord');

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setZipClass(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::PCLZIP);

// Saving the document as OOXML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save($temp_file);

header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="duplicates.docx"');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Expires: 0');

readfile($temp_file); 
file_get_contents($temp_file);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to address this issue by commenting out line 271 in PHPWord/src/PhpWord/Writer/Word2007.php. However, I am a novice at object-oriented programming, so this might not be a good solution.

```
private function addComments(ZipArchive $zip, &$rId): void
{
    $phpWord = $this->getPhpWord();
    $collection = $phpWord->getComments();
    $partName = 'comments';

    // Add comment relations and contents
    /** @var \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Collection\AbstractCollection $collection Type hint */
    if ($collection->countItems() > 0) {
        $this->relationships[] = ['target' => "{$partName}.xml", 'type' => $partName, 'rID' => ++$rId];

        // Write content file, e.g. word/comments.xml
        $writerPart = $this->getWriterPart($partName)->setElements($collection->getItems());
// Comment this line:        $zip->addFromString("word/{$partName}.xml", $writerPart->write());
    }
}
```